# Data Binding list to listbox C# XAML (Azure mobile services) UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, uwp, azure-mobile-services

So I have an online database. And I want the query results to be displayed in a listbox. I tried to use data binding but I think I'm doing it totally wrong.

Files

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Table

```
class ProductTable
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Seller { get; set; }
        public int Expiration { get; set; }
    }
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
namespace Test
{
    class MainViewModel
    {
        IMobileServiceTable<ProductTable> product = App.MobileService.GetTable<ProductTable>();

        //In this method, load your data into Products
        public async void Load()
        {
            // This query filters out completed TodoItems.
            MobileServiceCollection<ProductTable, ProductTable> Products = await product
                .Where(ProductTable => ProductTable.Price == 15)
                .ToCollectionAsync();

            // itemsControl is an IEnumerable that could be bound to a UI list control
            IEnumerable itemsControl = Products;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
    <Page x:Name="PAGE"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test;assembly=Version1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.DataContext>
                <local:MainViewModel />
            </Grid.DataContext>
            <ListBox Margin="10,10,10,100" x:Name="lb" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="10"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="10"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="10"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </Page>
```

**Solution**

Table needs JSON property name explicitly declared otherwise you won't be able to use data binding.

Table.cs

```
public class ProductTable
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Price")]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Seller")]
    public string Seller { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Expiration")]
    public int Expiration { get; set; }
}
```

XAML.cs
You don't need to declare a new listbox, only use itemsource.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IMobileServiceTable<ProductTable> productTest = App.MobileService.GetTable<ProductTable>();

    // This query filters out completed TodoItems.
    MobileServiceCollection<ProductTable, ProductTable> products = await productTest
        .Where(ProductTable => ProductTable.Type == "Test")
        .ToCollectionAsync();

    lb.ItemsSource = products;

}
```

XAML

**IN THE STACKPANEL, NEVER EVER USE HEIGHT"*" this will cause a critical error!**

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb" Margin="10,10,10,100" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Width="300">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  FontSize="10"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="10"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="10"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating two ListBoxes - one in code that isn't being displayed and one in XAML which is bound to whatever your DataContext is.

Remove the last two lines in your code, and change your XAML to:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
```

Next, expose Products as a Property on a class (ViewModel if you want to use MVVM), and ensure that the DataContext of your ListBox is set to said ViewModel/class.

I'm not familiar with MobileServiceCollection, so I assume it is bindable. If it is not, expose Products as a ObservableCollection (if the values in it change over time), or any other supported collection type.

**Elaboration on Properties**

Create a class:

```
public class MainViewModel {
    //This is a property
    public ObservableCollection<ProductTable> Products { get; set; }

    //In this method, load your data into Products
    public void Load(){ 
        //Products = xxx
    }
}
```

In your XAML:

```
<Page [...]
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace;assembly=YourProjectName">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:MainViewModel />
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <!-- ListBox goes in here somewhere, still with ItemsSource bound to Products -->
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Read more about namespaces [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086(v=vs.110).aspx).

By doing this, your Windows' DataContext will be set to the MainViewModel (could also be named ProductsViewModel). Since your ListBox will be within your Window, it will inherit (due to [Property Value Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197(v=vs.110).aspx)) the same DataContext.

The `Binding` will look for a property 'Products' on the ViewModel.

You will need to call the `Load()` method somewhere.

**Part 2 - After looking at the code**

Mind you, I am not able to run the code, so I'm flying somewhat blind.

Buy.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class Buy : Page
{
    private readonly MainViewModel _viewModel;

    public Buy()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        _viewModel = new MainViewModel();
        DataContext = _viewModel;
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _viewModel.Load();
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    IMobileServiceTable<ProductTable> product = App.MobileService.GetTable<ProductTable>();

    public List<ProductTable> Products { get; private set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public async void Load()
    {
        Products = await product
            .Where(ProductTable => ProductTable.Price == 15)
            .ToListAsync();

        //Notify that the property has changed to alert to UI to update.
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Products)));
    }
}
```

You need to make ProductTable public, or you will get a compilation error.

Hopefully, the above will enable you to bind your ListBox using the ItemsSource binding described above.

And please note that the above code is not necessarily best practice.

Comment: So I'm still learning c# so can you give an example of what you mean. Because I have no idea what you mean with: "Next, expose Products as a Property on a class (ViewModel if you want to use MVVM), and ensure that the DataContext of your ListBox is set to said ViewModel/class."

Comment: So I tried to use your code but <Window> isn't supported for windows universal so I tried to replace it with the <Page> element, can you please have a look at my code now. I know I'm being pretty annoying but I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: @user6480540: Ah yes. I've mostly done WPF, so Page it is. It was just an example. To you `local`, you need to declare it as a namespace. I'll add the example to my XAML.

Comment: So I'm starting to feel like a complete moron but I tried it with page. I used a separate class for MainViewModel because I can't use a nested class. But I have 2 problems now :). The first still MainViewModel does not exist in namespace second being all pages have a error in the InitializeComponent.

If you don't have a solution could you please give me a new approach to use a query, because I'm building this app for school and if I can't get this working my whole app will fail.

Comment: Can you .zip your solution and upload it somewhere, or can you put it on github or similar? I will gladly take a look, but it's a bit hard to communicate over this forum.

Comment: Here is a link to my Onedrive with a zip of the project: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AibJ3xyb_9pshr9aITcXHGeAIANHuw P.S. I really appreciate what your doing for me.

Comment: Haha, still the same errors. Think I need to try a new approach because this doesn't seem to work. I added the new version to Onedrive. Is there maybe an easier way? Because every uwp app with database needs mobile service but nobody is explaining how to use it. So either all the people building uwp apps with a database are professionals or I'm just really stupid :).

Comment: I've never used Azure, so I don't know exactly what the MobileServiceCollection does. What error are you getting? Do you get an exception?

Comment: So I solved the problem I'm not using MVVM as you used but it works. Could you please tell me in short what the purpose/advantage of MVVM is. But I really appreciate the time you took to help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The TL;DR of MVVM is to separate concerns. So data loading is Model, Logic is ViewModel and presentation is View. MVVM is the de facto standard for WPF (and UWP). It is closely related to MVC and other patterns. One big advantage is that it enables you to unit test logic without resorting to UI testing such as Coded UI.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need that line in your code behind

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
```

and  you can keep that line

```
lb.ItemsSource = Products;
```

or you can sit the Binding to the MobileServiceCollection in the XAML

```
<ListBox Margin="10,10,10,100" x:Name="lb" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```